# How can I localize day name with strftime in ruby Sinatra

Tags: ruby, localization, sinatra, strftime

What is the best way to localise strftime in ruby (sinatra app) to have day name in French for example ?

I have :

```
"2012-06-04".strftime("%a") # => "Mon"
```

I want :

```
"2012-06-04".strftime("%a") # => "Lun"
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [R18n internationalization](http://r18n.rubyforge.org/) gem. In your case `sinatra-r18n` gem. It supports several locales.

Taken from the [sinatra example page](http://r18n.rubyforge.org/sinatra.html):

```
set :default_locale, 'fr'
```

This will make the default locale to french.

Comment: Ok, finally it works! The right syntax is l(Time.now, '%B') # => Juin
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here are three solutions to your issue:

**1)** You can override the method strftime and doing something like this (inside the right class)

```
class XXX #put the right name 
  DAY ={
    "Mon" => "Lun",
    "Tue" => "Mar",
    ...
    }

  alias :old_strftime :strftime #Keep a reference to the old method

  def strftime(arg)
    DAY[old_strftime(arg)] 
  end

end
```

Or:

**2) [Recommended]** just use the DAY hash used above in your code and go for

```
DAY["2012-06-04".strftime("%a")]
```

**3)** subclass the class mentioned before (prefix it by "French" and insert the code above).

Comment: This would break all use of `strftime("something not %a")`.

Comment: Yeah if he uses something else than %a; he should use the 2nd solution